# How to filter log file for string inside single quotes?

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep, cut

I have a log file, which outputs information this way:

```
2016-01-01: foo bar fnord
2016-01-01: this is static 'this is of interest' some blob bar
2016-01-01: this is static 'this is of interest' some hurz poit
2016-01-01: foo bar fnord
2016-01-01: this is static 'this is of interest as well' some blob bar
```

I want to only print the string inside the single quotes, and duplicates entries should be removed, as in:

```
this is of interest
this is of interest as well
```

I tried working with regexes that look for the content in between quotes, yet I didn't manage to get them working, e.g.:

```
grep -io "static.*" |  sed -e '\w+'|'\w+(\s\w+)*'
```

Answer (score 3):

`cut` is simpler to use than writing a regex:

```
grep -io "static.*" logfile.txt | cut  -d "'" -f2 | sort -u
```

manages to do the trick. It prints:

```
this is of interest
this is of interest as well
```

Comment: uniq will only remove adjacent duplicates; you would want to sort its input first (or just use 'sort -u') -- further assuming you don't care about the original order.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a "sed-only" solution:

```
sed -n 's/^.*'\''\([^'\'']*\)'\''.*$/\1/p' file
```

This breaks down to

- `sed -n` in combination with the `p`option at the end of the pattern: print only matching lines
- `'\''`is shell notation to specify a single quote inside of a single-quoted string (the `'s/…/…/p'` argument)
- therefore the pattern `^.*'\''\([^'\'']*\)'\''.*$` matches lines starting with any character sequence (`^.*`), followed by a single quote ', a sequence of characters which are not single quotes (`[^'\'']*`), followed by a single quote ', and finally any remaining characters up to the end of the line (`.*$`).
- `([^'\'']*\)`is enclosed in parantheses so `sed`will store this part of the match into variable `\1`
- Finally, `s/pattern_explained_above/\1/p`replaces the entire matching line with the contents of variable `\1` (namely, the string part inside single quotes) and prints it (`p` option). All other lines which do not match the pattern are suppressed because of the `-n` option

Comment: That looks ... intense. Could you please describe the regex? What is each part doing?

Comment: @k0pernikus I updated the answer with a description. I hope it makes sense 

Answer (score 1):

try

```
awk -F\' '/static/ { if (!seen[$2]++) print $2 ;}'
```

with

- `static` being static string
- `!seen[$2]++` will be true first time, then false
- `-F\'` use `'` as separator